# How do I import an externally built dependency list into a gradle script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle script that builds a project including a list of dependencies that are generated through an external process. The build works fine if I include the dependencies directly in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0'
    runtime 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'
    runtime 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    ...
}
```

However, this list changes and is built by an external process.

I would like to import the dependency list from an external file built separately

```
dependencies {
   import 'deps.gradle'
}
```

But I don't see how this is possible with anything I'm seeing in gradle.

Another option I've explored is building the dependency list dynamically within the gradle build using a plugin -- but I've not been able to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is using the `apply`command. Make sure the path to your file is good and you should be in business!

```
dependencies {
   apply from: "deps.gradle"
}
```

For more information see [point 21.3.1 on the gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)